# Best database system option that is stored in a file without need of a server?

Tags: c#, .net, database

I'm developing an application in *C#* (.NET Framework v3.5) and I need to store some tables with relationships between them in a database.

**What would a good database system to include in my application and why?**

**Important:** I don't want my client to install a server (like MySQL or SQL Server), unless it is installed with .NET Framework v3.5.

I have been thinking about *SQLite* and *Microsoft Access* because both store the database in a file instead of a server, but I'm just wondering if there are any other options I have. For example, just for testing purpose, I modeled my database using Entity Framework and I stored it in a .mdf file, and worked fine, but I'm not really sure if SQL Server is required to query/modify/insert info into that .mdf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server CE (compact edition) doesn't require any installation, you just need to deploy the appropriate DLL with your application. The database is stored in a file, no server is needed.

SQLite and SQL Server CE both support the Entity Framework (use [this connector](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) for SQLite)

Comment: @Thomas Does SQLite support Entity Framework, when doing Model first with that connector?

Comment: @Oscar, what do you call "model first"? You mean "code first"?

Comment: @Thomas I mean creating the model and generating the database from the model

Comment: @Thomas I read on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) that SQLite support is only for *code first*. I think I will use SQL Server CE 3.5, although there are some features I cannot use in Entity Framework (like *Skip()*, Identity fields that autoincrements,...). I think you could specify in your answer that SQLite is only supported in EF in *code first*, just in case someone else find this answer useful :)

Comment: @Oscar, that's not true... I used SQLite with Entity Framework long before EF Code First was released. I don't know if it can generate the DB from the model, but I'm certain you don't have to use the code first approach.

Comment: As for SQL Server CE, version 4 was released a few weeks ago, and supports results paging (Skip/Take) and identity fields

Comment: @Thomas I will have to try that connector then. Maybe what I have is a concept problem. What I read is that you cannot design the model, and then generate the table using SQLite and EF. Anyway, I'm downloading the connector to test it by myself. About SQL Serve CE 4, will it require .NET Framework v4 installed on the machine it will be running?

Comment: @Oscar, not it requires only .NET 3.5 SP1. But generating the DB from the model is only supported since EF 4.0, so you will need .NET 4.0 anyway...

Comment: @Thomas hmm.. I'm a little lost here. I'm working on a project (in VS2010 but under .NET Framework v3.5) and I'm able to create a model and generate the SQL script from it :/

Comment: Are you sure you're targeting 3.5? The CreateDatabase/CreateDatabaseScript methods are new in 4.0...

Answer (score 1):

I agree that SQLite is a good choice.  It's a powerful, widely used (Firefox, Mac OS, Google Gears, you name it) database in a small package.  It's in the public domain, and there's a convenient [.NET binding](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) including a ADO.NET provider.  I've used it myself in a WinForms application.

Comment: What provided has you used for SQLite in .NET?

Comment: @Oscar, sorry, just added the link.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx)